# How to decorate functions with different signatures in Golang?

Tags: go, decorator

I tried to apply decorators from this famous [Golang decorators talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyDkyFjzFVc) but it only works for him because all the functions he's decorating are attached to a struct, and he's just decorating one Do() function. Every other tutorial I've seen also does it this way, which is quite annoying.

I want to decorate these functions with a base58/64 encoder function

```
func SpendTx(senderID, recipientID string, amount, fee utils.BigInt, payload string, ttl, nonce uint64) (rlpRawMsg []byte, err error)
func NamePreclaimTx(accountID, commitmentID string, fee uint64, ttl, nonce uint64) (rlpRawMsg []byte, err error)
func NameClaimTx(accountID, name string, nameSalt, fee uint64, ttl, nonce uint64) (rlpRawMsg []byte, err error)
...
```

As you can see, the arguments are all different, and they are also pure functions, not attached to a struct. But they all return []byte and an error, so this should be possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer the only decoration I've done is through embedding structs, but one way could be to define a type for the function you'd like to decorate (not strictly necessary but will make signatures simpler):

```
type SpendTXFn = func SpendTx(senderID, recipientID string, amount, fee utils.BigInt, payload string, ttl, nonce uint64) (rlpRawMsg []byte, err error)
```

Now functions can talk in terms of this type, a decorator function would contain the same call signature as this type

```
func EncodedSpendTX(s SpendTX) SpendTX {
     return func(senderID, recipientID string, amount, fee utils.BigInt, payload string, ttl, nonce uint64) (rlpRawMsg []byte, err error) {
        // compute decorated result 
        res, err := s(senderID, recipientID, amount, fee, payload, ttl, nonce)
        if err != nil {
          return res, err
        } 
        // encode the res
        // return encoded res
     }
}
```

Now you can decorate your SpendTX function:

```
decorated := EncodedSpendTX(originalSpendTx)

decorated(...) -> []byte, err
```

Downsides of this is there is a decorator per function type.  Upsides are [many with my favorite being](https://medium.com/dm03514-tech-blog/designpatterns-considering-decorators-b4968a8006e8) that the encoding is easy to test and separate from the original logic, so it doesn't require any mutation to your original function.

---

Actually I think this is the approach that go's http middleware takes through `http.Handler`

https://www.alexedwards.net/blog/making-and-using-middleware